# Adding Visual Studio Team Services server in Team Explorer keeps on loading without adding

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I've created a team project collection in visualstudio.com and added team members to that.

However, when the team members try to add this server in the team explorer in visual studio, the server just doesn't get added and instead just hangs at the below screen.

[image]

I'm just not able to figure out what's wrong here. I checked the access to the users and that is set to 'Basic' which provides basic VSTS accesses.

Am I missing anything else? Can someone point it out please in case I've missed anything?

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't any other setting required. Usually, a sign in dialog will pop up after clicking OK button. How long does it keep on loading? Do you have proxy configured in your network?

Comment: There is no proxy configured and I'm already signed in into Visual Studio with the same account that is given access above.

Comment: It just keeps loading without even a message that it's not responding. note that I'm able to cancel it even after ~4 hours in this state.

Comment: Then can you try to sign out from the VS first and then add the URL to see if there is a sign in dialog popup?

Comment: Tried this too. Waited for around 7~8 mins. Still the same outcome.

Comment: I restarted my PC after logging out of VS. Then After I tried to add the server, I got the popup and it eventually got added.